# ComboBox SelectedValue always null, cannot be set

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedvalue

I’m working on a C#.Net 4.0 Winforms app., and am experiencing some difficulty with two comboboxes always returning `NULL` for their `SelectedValue` properties.

I have three combos on this form. The first combo is databound to a BindingSoucce which in turn has a typed DataTable as its DataSource. That combo works as expected.

The other two combos are bound to local, generic DataTables. These are the ones that fail.
The offending combos are cmbDays and cmbYears. Their data tables are populated in code via simple loops. Both tables contain data at the end of their population calls. `dtDaysLU` contains string column ‘Day’. `dtYearsLU` contains string column ‘Year.’ Pretty simple.

The code that binds up the BindingSources and combos looks like this:

```
private void databindPermitDateCombos() 
{
    this.cmbMonth.DataBindings.Clear();
    this.cmbDay.DataBindings.Clear();
    this.cmbYear.DataBindings.Clear();

    this._bsMonthsLU.DataSource = null;
    this._bsDaysLU.DataSource = null;
    this._bsYearsLU.DataSource = null;

    this._manipulator.DataBindBindingSource(this._bsMonthsLU, this._ds.tblMonthsLU);
    this._manipulator.DataBindBindingSource(this._bsDaysLU, this._dtDays);
    this._manipulator.DataBindBindingSource(this._bsYearsLU, this._dtYears);

    this._manipulator.DataBindComboBox(this.cmbMonth, this._bsMonthsLU, "Month", "MonthNumber");
    this._manipulator.DataBindComboBox(this.cmbDay, this._bsDaysLU, "Day", "Day");
    this._manipulator.DataBindComboBox(this.cmbYear, this._bsYearsLU, "Year", "Year");
}
```

… where  _manipulator.DataBindComboBox  looks like this:

```
public void DataBindComboBox(ComboBox combo, BindingSource bindingSource, string displayMemberName, string valueMemberName)
{
    combo.DataBindings.Clear();
    combo.DisplayMember = displayMemberName;
    combo.ValueMember = valueMemberName;
    combo.DataSource = bindingSource;
}
```

You can see that none of this is rocket science. I did want to point out the order in which the combobox properties are set – per MSDN suggestion:

- Display member
- Value member
- DataSource

In code I attempt to set the SelectedValue  of these combos like so:

```
this.cmbMonth.SelectedValue = this._permitMonthNum;
this.cmbDay.SelectedValue = this._permitDay.ToString();
this.cmbYear.SelectedValue = this._permitYear.ToString();
```

Note that I do a `.ToString()` on the member data as I set the `SelectedValue` of both of those combos because the code that populates their underlying tables uses string types:

`this._dtDays.Columns.Add("Day", typeof(string));`

So I know it’s not a datatype mismatch.

And debugging shows the `.SelectedValue` properties null for both the `cmbDay` and `cmbYear` combos.

Comment: What is the combobox dropdownstyle property?

Comment: What's the value of _permitDay and is it in the _bsDaysLU list?  You keep clearing DataBindings but you never show any DataBindings getting added.

Comment: Steve: the style is DropDown.

Comment: LarsTech:

The bindings are added in the calls to:
this._manipulator.DataBindBindingSource(this._bsMonthsLU, this._ds.tblMonthsLU);
    this._manipulator.DataBindBindingSource(this._bsDaysLU, this._dtDays);
    this._manipulator.DataBindBindingSource(this._bsYearsLU, this._dtYears);

    this._manipulator.DataBindComboBox(this.cmbMonth, this._bsMonthsLU, "Month", "MonthNumber");
    this._manipulator.DataBindComboBox(this.cmbDay, this._bsDaysLU, "Day", "Day");
    this._manipulator.DataBindComboBox(this.cmbYear, this._bsYearsLU, "Year", "Year");

Comment: @LarsTech: Hmm - I will take a look at the value of _permitDay and ensure it is in the BindingSource list. Sadly I had not actually checked that. And we all know where assumptions get us.

Comment: DataBindings and DataSource are two different things, which is why I brought that up.  I don't see anything like `cmbDay.DataBindings.Add(...)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok @LarsTech - you were on the right path. Seems this logic fork bypassed the function to populate my datatables. So, yup - there was nothing in my list to match to.

Thank you so very much for the fresh eyes. I was so stuck in the assumption that the tables had data from a previous call, that it didn't dawn on me to verify.

Thanks!

Kurt